# SetInterval brings back previous data

Tags: javascript, ajax, settimeout, message

So, I am trying to build a simple function to bring all the messages between two users. Like an chat app. I am using setInterval to refresh the messages in case some of the users inserted an new message in the database, but something it's happening:
When I select a conversation, and then select another one, the function is bringing back the messages of the previous conversation for a second before showing the messages of the new selected conversation. Here it is:

```
    // Load messages
    $(".from_messages").click(function() {
        $("#messageList").empty();
        var from = $(this).attr('user_id');
        var user = <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>;
        $("input[name='to']").val(from);
        retrieve(from, user);
    })

    //Interval
    function retrieve(from, user) {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            $("#messageList").empty();
            $.ajax({
                url: "server.php",
                method: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {"from": from, "user": user},
                success: function(response) {
                    if(response != "") {
                        $(response).each(function(index, item) {
                            if(item.from_id == user) {
                                $("#messageList").append('<div class="col-12 text-right"><p class="w-50 ml-auto">- '+item.message+'</p></div><br>');
                            } else {
                                $("#messageList").append('<div class="col-12"><p class="w-50">- '+item.message+'</p></div><br>');
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
        }, 3000)
    }
```

[image: This is the first selected conversation, with user Sandro]

[image: Here is the conversation with Moises. And before, showing it's messages, Sandro ones are being shown for half of a second]

If somebody can help me, I would be eternally grateful. And here is a link that I hope could show what I am facing: [Video demostration](https://streamable.com/jbdmu8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval(f, n)` will fire `f` every `n` milliseconds until you clear the interval. When you call `setInterval`, it returns a reference to the interval. Save that reference and call `clearInterval(reference)` when you want the interval to stop--in this case before creating a new interval when you select a different conversation.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am adding `var interval_id = interval; return interval_id;` at the end of the interval function to return the interval reference and then catch it in the other function at the beginning with `var reference = retrieve(from, user); clearInterval(reference);` But is not working.

Comment: I would store the reference to the interval on the window. Something like `var interval; function retrieve(......){ interval = setInterval(....); }` You could also return the interval from your `retrieve` function and store it somewhere where you can access it between calls of your `click` handler function.

Comment: Thank you so much, David. Declaring the variable out of the function worked good. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.